# How to handle arguments with spaces in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to have my Discord bot handle commands with spaces in the argument. My `args` variable is defined in my `index.js` file:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

My command file (`perk.js`) looks like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const PerkData = require('./perk.json');


module.exports = {
    name: 'perk',
    args: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        for (let i = 0; i < PerkData.perks.length; i++) {
            if (PerkData.perks[i].id.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase()) {
                const perkEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                    .setColor('#000000')
                    .setTitle('__**' + PerkData.perks[i].name + '**__ ')
                    .setURL(PerkData.perks[i].url)
                    .setThumbnail(PerkData.perks[i].gif)
                    .setDescription('A teachable unique [' + PerkData.perks[i].character + '](' + PerkData.perks[i].characterURL + ') Perk <:Perk:833657215743295499>. It can be unlocked for all other characters from Level ' + PerkData.perks[i].lvl + ' onwards:')
                    .addField('__Description__', PerkData.perks[i].description, false)

                message.channel.send(perkEmbed)
            }
        }
   }     
}
```

As of this moment, I have an "id" field in the JSON file that has hyphens `-` instead of spaces, which then the `perk.js` file reads from it and matches it up with the description.
Example: `.perk ace-in-the-hole`

How do I make it so that I can use spaces in the argument instead of having to use hyphens?

Do I need to change how `args` is defined in `index.js`? Or can it be done within the command file, `perk.js`?

Long story short, I have: `.perk ace-in-the-hole` working.
But I want to be able to do this: `.perk ace in the hole`

(Sorry if this was poorly written, I'm not an experienced coder...)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply join the array of arguments with a space.

```js
execute(message, args) {
    // Join the args array
    let perkArg = args.join(' ')
    
    for (let i = 0; i < PerkData.perks.length; i++) {
        if (PerkData.perks[i].id.toLowerCase() === perkArg.toLowerCase()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming all the perk IDs are unique and you only want to send one message, you could also search through the whole `PerkData.perks` array in a single line without a for loop to find a single item.

```js
// Join the args array
let perkArg = args.join(' ')
let perk = PerkData.perks.find(perk => perk.id === perkArg.toLowerCase())
if(perk !== undefined) {
    // perk was found
} else {
    // perk was not found
}
```